# as3 - what's the difference when you put () at the end?

Tags: actionscript-3

if you say for instance

```
instance:Instance = new Instance();
```

or

```
instance:Instance = new Instance;
```

Why does it matter? It's empty anyways so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript's compiler running in strict or standard mode allows for that syntax for instantiating an object. The class' `nullary` (zero arity) constructor is called either way and thus the resulting object is the same...

Most of Actionscript's language syntax is derived from [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) so if you are looking for someone to blame... ;-)

A lot of languages enforce the `()` syntax to visual distinguish function/methods vs. properties but that is strictly in the language designer's hands.... *Personally* I use the `()` syntax as a visual cue as I work in a few different languages and all the others require it...

Comment: That answer is very loose and not very precise. It deserves a vote down. What's missing of course is that the syntax is only allowed in one single case: Object instantiation does not require parameters. Instead the answer implies that omitting parentheses is always allowed which is of course not true.